# How does tension in string change when object suspended from it is dipped in water?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, buoyancy, vibrations, string, fluid-statics

A copper cylinder hangs from the bottom of a steel wire of negligible mass. The top of the wire is attached to the ceiling, and once struck the wire emits a sound with a fundamental frequency of 300Hz.

Now I understand that the tension force is equal to *mg* which I can replace the *m* by density x volume. Here's what I don't understand. If I were to dip the cyclinder into water such that half its volume is submerged, then why will the tension force be (density of copper) * volume * g - 1/2 (density of water) * (volume) * (g)?

The trouble im having is why do we subtract 1/2 (density of water)(volume)(g).
*I understand where the half came from but not why we subtract that.

Comment: Hint: [Archimedes' principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedes%27_principle)

Comment: Tension and buoyancy act together upward against weight. Their sum is equal to the weight.

Comment: Are you familiar with the concept of buoyancy?  When you are submerged in water, is the *net* vertical force acting on you still mg, or is it something less?

Answer (score 1):

When the cylinder is half submerged it experiences pressure from the water over its lower half surface (which is in contact with the water). The net result of this pressure is an upward force on the cylinder equal to the weight of the water displaced by the cylinder. This can be understood by imagining the cylinder removed from the water and replaced by a half cylinder of water. The pressure is still there pressing on the surface of the water used to replace the half cylinder. And that pressure must be supporting the weight of the half cylinder of water because that half cylinder stays there in equilibrium. Hence the pressure exerts a net upward force equal to the weight of the half cylinder of water. It exerts the same force on the cylinder itself when that is there.